# Issue with clicking download button on macrotrends - python/selenium/chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to download CSV file by clicking **Download Data** button using python/selenium/chromedriver from url: https://www.macrotrends.net/assets/php/stock_price_history.php?t=META

Here is the code:

```
import time
from pathlib import Path

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

CWD = Path.cwd()
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_prefs = {
    "download.default_directory": f"{CWD}",
    "safebrowsing.enabled": False,
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", chrome_prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")


ticker = "META"
url = f"https://www.macrotrends.net/assets/php/stock_price_history.php?t={ticker}"
with webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options) as driver:
    start_time = time.time()
    print(f"url: {url}")
    driver.get(url)
    download_button = None
    try:
        wd_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        download_button = wd_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "chart_buttons")))
        time_diff = time.time() - start_time
        print(f"page load done in {time_diff:.2f} seconds.")
    except:
        print("ERROR: page load timeout!")
        raise SystemExit()

    start_time = time.time()
    print(f"download_button type: {type(download_button)}")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", download_button)
    time_diff = time.time() - start_time
    print(f"click done in {time_diff:.2f} seconds.")
    csv_file = CWD.joinpath(f"MacroTrends_Data_Download_{ticker}.csv")
    assert csv_file.is_file(), f"{csv_file} not found!"
    print(f"download done in {time_diff:.2f} seconds.")
```

LOG:

```
python .\mtrends_download.py

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59481/devtools/browser/0ef013e3-b442-45d8-b96b-a230e3b27047
url: https://www.macrotrends.net/assets/php/stock_price_history.php?t=META
page load done in 1.34 seconds.
download_button type: <class 'selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement'>
[0610/160508.114:INFO:CONSOLE(344)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'goal')", source: https://www.macrotrends.net/assets/php/stock_price_history.php?t=META (344)
click done in 0.20 seconds.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "{SCRIPT_PATH}\mtrends_download.py", line 47, in <module>
    assert csv_file.is_file(), f"{csv_file} not found!"
AssertionError: {SCRIPT_PATH}\MacroTrends_Data_Download_META.csv not found!
```

Is there any way or a better way to download this csv file successfully using selenium in python headless mode? Thanks!

When I download the csv file manually from chrome browser app, I still notice "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'goal')" in the console but I am able download it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way:

```py
import os, time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def download_file(path, ticker):

    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    prefs = {'download.default_directory': path}
    options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

    driver = Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get(f'https://www.macrotrends.net/assets/php/stock_price_history.php?t={ticker}')
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    start_time = time.time()
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.dataExport.chart_buttons.btn.btn-danger.btn-xs'))).click()

    while True:
        is_exist = os.path.exists(f"{path}\\MacroTrends_Data_Download_{ticker}.csv")
        if is_exist:
            print(f"The file is downloaded!")
            break
    time_diff = time.time()-start_time
    print(f"download done in {time_diff:.2f} seconds.")

# PATH to download the file
PATH = 'D:\\test'
ticker = "META"
download_file(PATH, ticker)
```

output:

```
The file is downloaded!
download done in 0.73 seconds.
```

things to note:

1. make sure the PATH (here for example, `D:\\test`) already exists.
2. you need to wait until the file gets fully downloaded on your machine before closing the Selenium browser.

you can cross-check the availability of the file at the given path. (in the example above, `D:\test\MacroTrends_Data_Download_META.csv`)